# what is the cokernel of this map? $ a\in R, \ \ f_a:M\rightarrow M \ \ f_a(m)=a\cdot m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

consider a commutative unitary ring $R$ and $M$ is an $R$-module.
For $ a\in R, \ \ f_a:M\rightarrow M  \ \ f_a(m)=a\cdot m$ is a homomorphism.
 What is the kernel and cokernel of this map?

The kernel I found is $ker=\{ m\in M \ | f_a(m)=O_m\}= \{ m\in M \ | a\cdot m=O_m\}=\{O_m\} $

I am not sure about the final equality.

I know that cokernel is equal to $\frac{M}{Imf_a}$

how can I find cokernel?

how can I express cokernel of any map as a set? like for kernel $ker=\{ m\in M \ | f_a(m)=O_m\}$ how can I write cokernel?
I mean
$coker=\{ m+Imf_a \ |  \ \ \ \ ?  \ \ \ \ \}$

please help

Comment: In your description of the kernel, why is the last equality true?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I thought for for $a\neq0 $ m should be $O_m$

Comment: Consider $M = R = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ with $f_a(m) = am$.  Then $\operatorname{ker} f_2 \neq \{0\}$.  Also, I'm not sure you're going to get a nice description of either the kernel or cokernel in the generality you asked.  I am not an algebraist, though....

Comment: @JasonDeVito so shall I write it as $\{ m\in M \ | a\cdot m=O_m\}$ ?

Comment: You could.  Whether or not you should depends on what you're doing with it...

Comment: Ok got it. Do you know how can I express cokernel of any map as a set? like for kernel $ker=\{ m\in M \ | f_a(m)=O_m\}$ how can I write cokernel?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do any better than $M/\operatorname{Im} f_a$

Comment: isn't that just $M/aM$ and that should be as good as it gets.